# How to select all items in windows phone list picker

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have windows phone list picker Control in my code I bind the items from c#.i.e, items comes from services .I have to keep "select all" item .so that i can select all the items at once.I added "select all" .On checking the "Select All" check box .I could  not get any event to execute the code so that all check boxes are checked and UI get reflected

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
private void SelectAll(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    yourlistbox.SelectAll();
}
```

For more information check out the documentation in msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Im not sure if this the right way, But this works

```
 List<object> arr = new List<object>((((System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>)(s))).Values);
     for (int k = 0; k < data.Length; k++)
                {
                    object selectitem = arr[k];
                    items.Add(selectitem);
                }
   yourlistbox.SelectedItems = items;
```

This is how i made it work in my case so the way is to create a list object containing all elements from your data source and assigning to to selected items.

Comment: my question is how can i  get check box checked event and it must reflect in UI . Not after selection changed event is fired and also in wp8 i cannot see SelectAll() method for list picker

Comment: Where should I add above code.To update my UI when "Select All" check box checked

Comment: On click of select all an event will be fired , put this code there

Comment: In Toolkit list picker in multiple mode we cant get Click Event for an item

Comment: well you can get, otherwise whats the need for list picker with multiple selection.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with LongListMultiSelector

See here

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-31-Multiple-Selection-with-the-LongListMultiSelector

http://winphone8dev.blogspot.in/2012/12/longlistmultiselector.html?m=1